# Link Click event exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

How is it possible to take a true result if a link click event exists?

Using google tag manager there is an event `gtm.linkClick`.

Using simple custome code and without use of gtm is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var foo = $.data( gtm, 'events' ).click // you can use your object instead of "gtm"
// you can query $.data( object, 'events' ) 
// and get an object back, then see what events are attached to it.

$.each( foo, function(i,o) {
    alert(i) // guid of the event
    alert(o) // the function definition of the event handler
});
```